# Splash Screen doesn't go away after 5 Seconds

Tags: android

I' ve just started today learning Android. I' am having a issue where am not able to hide the splash screen after 5 seconds. When the application is launched, it shows the splash screen and according to the code it should disappear after 5 Seconds.

Please help, below are all the code you need.

***Project Explorer***

[image]

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.windows8.myapplication" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.windows8.myapplication.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

***splash.java***

```
package com.example.windows8.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.windows8.myapplication.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call `start` method on your `timer` field - so you just don't start the thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in straight and simple way:

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.windows8.myapplication.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        } ,5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.windows8.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.windows8.myapplication.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };
```

The thread you have started, is technically correct to avoid possible ANR due to wait of 5 seconds

In general, you have to call thread.run() to run the code block within the thread. And this should be post Thread declaration complete.

Also, you are starting the new activity in the Thread. The activities normally executes on UI thread, so declare the handler and use the handler to start the new activity.

```
    }

}
```

Following is the code fragment which is correct

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    Handler hander = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message m){
            Intent intent = new Intent (MyActivity.this, Next.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    pubilc void onCreate(Bundle ic)
    {
       //your code setContentView() etc....
       Thread toRun = new Thread()
       {
              public void run()
              {
                   try
                   {
                      sleep(5000);
                   } 
                   catch (InterruptedException e)
                   {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                ,  }
                    hander.sendMessage(1); 
              }
       }
       toRun.start();
    }
}
```